# FastReport: different languages

Tags: delphi, layout, document, hint

I have an application with reports in different languages ​​(NL/D/ENG). The dates are DD/MM/YYYY by default. Now I want to display the days and months in the correct language in the view. Example: NL = Monday, D=Montag, ENG = Monday
How can I achieve this in FastReport?